# How to stop a 555 timer

Tags: 555

I have a 555 timer set up so each cycle it will count up a 7 segment display.

clock output of 555 goes to a [CD4026B](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4026b.pdf) clock input , this feeds the 7 seg display.

I would like when the 7-segment display reads 9 9  the 555 timer turns off.  Any idea how i can do this?

Comment: First you draw a schematic. Then you modify it, or ask us how to modify it.

Comment: Can you say more about why you want to do this? In many digital design contexts it would be be better to have an ENABLE signal control whether logic responds to a clock than to stop the clock itself. For example, if you just want to stop the counter from overflowing, this would probably be the way to go.

Comment: There is a pin on your counter labelled "Clock Inhibit". It's purpose is to inhibit the clock. You just have to make a circuit to work out when the output reads 9.

Comment: @ThePhoton I agree with your statement, but then again, if this is a timer... you want to restart the clock from zero, not at whatever part in the cycle it happens to be in.

Comment: @Trevor, then you probably want a user input to tell you when to reset the timer anyway, letting you use the reset logic of your counter. (When I said "this" in this is the way to go, I meant use an ENABLE signal, not halt the 555).

Comment: @ThePhoton yes I know, as I said, I agree with you.

Comment: No schematic.  Closing.

Comment: Your 555 has a reset input and your 4026 has a Clock_Inhibit input. Either one of these would work for what you're describing.

Comment: Actually ... "stopping" a 555 is  technically difficult. You CAN hold it in reset, but the first cycle when you release it will be longer than you expect since reset will discharge the capacitor to a lower value.

Comment: I have a circuit but not sure it would help much  , as the question i need to answer is is how to know when its at 99?  The "Clock Inhibit" will stop the counter which is good to know but what do i need to tell me, the 7 seg is at 9 send stop bit.

Comment: @EugeneSh. i can draw the whole circuit cause i dont know what to use to monitor the led and would send a disenable bit back once its 9 9

Comment: The 4026 is a bad choice if you want to know 'the number' as the 'counter' value is not available externally. You could try (1) decoding the two 7 segment displays for the value 99 (yuk!), (2) changing to a separate counter and display decoder/driver chip and decoding the BCD value of the counters  (3) add an easy to decode two decade counter (say 2 x 4017) in parallel to the 4026s fed from the same clock to mimic the count value or (4) use a micro controller  (pic, arduino) and do the whole thing in software using an I2C 7 segment display ( *which would be my preferred choice* ).

Comment: I would love to use a pic chip, but its been to long since i have wrote a program for one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With those counters you would need to decode the segments then disable the counter clocks.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGheQ4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: i believe this would work great, did not think about doing it this way.  but not sure why you have inverter on g,  it should be on e i believe.  as that would be the only led off on 9

Comment: @user41758 it is on e...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming detecting the rollover from 99 to 00 is acceptable, you can do this by detecting the **rising** edge of the carry output from the most significant digit (MSD) counter.

The obvious way to do that is to clock a CD4013 flip-flop with the carry output and use the Q or /Q output to inhibit the counter or reset the 555, most likely the latter is better. A low input on the /RESET pin of the 555 will hold the 555 output low.

To restart the counter reset both counters and the flip-flop.

You can avoid most of the longer first cycle issue mentioned by others if you precede the LSD counter with a prescaler such as a CD4040 and increase the 555 frequency to compensate. Reset the prescaler as well to restart, of course.

I'm not going to bother drawing a schematic since you didn't, but this is pretty straightforward if you know how a D flip-flop works.

After the timeout is reached, the display will show 00, and the 4013 outputs will have changed state- which you can use to illuminate an LED or whatever.

Comment: I understand , but cant have the roll over, so would not work correctly.

Comment: +1 for the prescaler. I thought about the carry thing too but it ended up as many, if not more, devices than my less complex, and self explanatory answer. Really weird the way the carry works on that thing huh.